# Scanner input stream undefined..?

Tags: java

I just copied and pasted this code straight from my Uni provided lecture notes:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Echo {
public static void main (String[] args) {
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Input a line of text");
  String message = console.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Your input was: "
       + message);
```

it keeps giving me the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor Scanner(InputStream) is undefined
at Scanner.main(Scanner.java:4)

i think it is reffering to the (System.in); section of code, but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You named your file Scanner.java, but you should have named it Echo.java. Java requires that file names and public class names be the same.

The specific error: javac thought you were defining a Scanner class, which was conflicting with `java.util.Scanner`. Had you fixed that, it would have complained about the class/filename mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

import `java.util.Scanner;`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Echo {
public static void main (String[] args) {
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input a line of text");
String message = console.nextLine();
System.out.println("Your input was: "
   + message);
```